# Troubles converting code to Gtk3

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'd like to rewrite a gtk python library to Gtk3 (gi.repository)
I'd like to ask you what does it include?

For instance library contained contructions like this

```
gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.TOP_LEFT_CORNER),
gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.TOP_RIGHT_CORNER),
gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER),
gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER) )
```

so I rewrote it to this

```
Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.TOP_LEFT_CORNER),
Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.TOP_RIGHT_CORNER),
Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER),
Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER) )
```

So basically what I did was that I opened ipython and google, and was guessing :/

My questions:

1. Is there somewhere some kind of list? What was replaced and where can I find given class/constant in a gi.repository?
   For instance I'd like to rewrite `gtk.CAN_FOCUS`, but I have no idea where do I find such constant in `gi.repository`
2. Am I doing it right?
3. If so, is there something I forgot to do?

Can somebody please explain, why was this change done? gtk2->gtk3, why just not upgrade old libraries?
And what does it include if I want to rewrite app for gtk3?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this in the future you can set this flag with this property.

```
drawing_area.set_property('can-focus', True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in interactive Python:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
dir(Gtk)
```

Comment: of course I know `dir` and `help` commands, but that gives you no quick way how to find out that `gtk.gdk.TOP_LEFT_CORNER` has been replaced by `Gdk.CursorType.TOP_LEFT_CORNER`, and it doesn't explain why such changes has been done

Comment: Well, since you heavily emphasized python I wasn't aware from your question that you were looking for a Gtk2 to Gtk3 porting guide.